# Showing line by line text on multiple line textbox

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, facebook-c#-sdk, c#-2.0

Hi guys when I retrieve my data from access database to my textbox multi line text boxs the data is show one beside one I want any line be in its line for example I have 5 line in my access field but in my text box show all of the data in same line what should I do any help please?

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + Application.StartupPath + "\\db\\it.accdb");

con.Open();

OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.CommandText = "select * from data where [ID] like(" + textBox9.Text + ")";
cmd.Connection = con;

var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString();
    textBox20.Text = reader["Description"].ToString();

    // ----------------------------------------------
    // These doesn't work with me :
    // ----------------------------------------------
    //textBox2.Text = Environment.NewLine;
    //textBox28.Text = textBox28.Text + Environment.NewLine;
    //textBox2.Text = textBox28.Text + Environment.NewLine;

}

con.Close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the string 'new line character' "\n" to create new lines. Like this:

```
textBox1.Text = reader["Name"].ToString() + "\n";
textBox20.Text = reader["Description"].ToString() + "\n";
```

Comment: thanks bro but its same the number is like that                        07704425588                       
0770258              but it show it like 077044255880770258

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
textBox1.Multiline = true;
textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;//Other settings is Horizontal and Both
textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
textBox1.WordWrap = true;

textBox20.Multiline = true;
textBox20.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;//Other settings is Horizontal and Both
textBox20.AcceptsReturn = true;
textBox20.WordWrap = true;

while (reader.Read())
{
    textBox1.Text += reader["Name"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
    textBox20.Text += reader["Description"].ToString() + Environment.NewLine;
}
```